# Laravel Eloquent or Query builder : Use OR conditions inside of AND Conditions

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

### Data flow :

4-5 Main Categories and each main category have 10-15 sub categories.
Few services which belongs to few categories. Categories are stored in services table as serialized data like this :

```
a:2:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:2:"3";}
a:1:{i:0;s:3:"2";}
a:1:{i:0;s:3:"3";}
a:2:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:3:"3";}
```

### Posted form data are as below :

```
array(
    [0] => array(
        [0] => 1,
        [1] => 3,
    ),
    [1] => array(
        [0] => 2
    ),
    ....
    ....
    ....
)
```

Where each selected categories which are in same main category are grouped in an array.Also the number of categories and subcategories are not fix

### Plain SQL to get records

```
SELECT * FROM `services` WHERE (`categories` LIKE '%"1"%' OR `categories` LIKE '%"3"%') AND (`categories` LIKE '%"2"%') AND ( ... OR ...) AND ( ... OR ...) ....
```

I've tied this but this seems to be not working.

```
\DB::table ('services')
->where(function($q) use ($categories) {
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $q->where('services.categories', 'like', '%"'.DB::raw($category).'"%');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The query in Laravel with query builder

```
$queryBuilder = \DB::table('services');

//loop to create dynamic where query
foreach($categories as $category){

        //create a query as (condition OR condition)
        $queryBuilder->where(function($query) use($category) {

            $query->where('categories', 'LIKE', "%" . $category[0] . "%");

            //if count is two then adding the or where clause 
            if(count($category) === 2){
                  $query->orWhere('categories', 'LIKE', "%" . $category[1] . "%");
            }

        });
    }
}

$result = $queryBuilder->get(); //executing the query to get result
```

Comment: Thank you Max for you response. But in the code how can we just hard code $category[0] or $category[1] because the categories array is dynamic too. We don't know how many categories are there


            `if(count($category) === 2){
                  $query->orWhere('categories', 'LIKE', "%" . $category[1] . "%");
            }`